# Using grep to check a naming convention follows a regular expression

Tags: r, regex

I'm testing a naming convention but i can't get the regular expression to be exact enough. Is there a way i can restrict the number of underscores, we have a set number of fields broken out by underscores but some of these are free text fields that I need to allow through. Here i am just wanting to check the structure of the fields.

```
nameP <- as.character("SX_anything_SX")  # correct: i.e. 1
nameP <- as.character("SX_anything__SX") # correct: i.e. 1 but should be incorrect
nameP <- as.character("SX_anything_SXS") # error on end: i.e. 0
nameP <- as.character("SXS_anything_SX") # error on start: i.e. 0

placement_regxpr <- '^[A-Z]{2}_.*_[A-Z]{2}$'
isMatch <- grep(pattern = placement_regxpr,x = nameP, ignore.case = TRUE)
isMatch
```

Comment: Try `^[A-Z]{2}_[^_]*_[A-Z]{2}$`, see https://regex101.com/r/Hp2v7j/1

Comment: yes thank you and thanks for the 101 link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
placement_regxpr <- '^[A-Z]{2}_[^_]*_[A-Z]{2}$'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hp2v7j/1)

The regex will only match:

- `^` - start of a string
- `[A-Z]{2}` - two ASCII letters (since `ignore.case = TRUE` is used, this character class/bracket expression will match both lower- and uppercase letters)
- `_` - an underscore
- `[^_]*` - 0 or more chars other than `_`
- `_` - an underscore
- `[A-Z]{2}` - two ASCII letters
- `$` - end of a string.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, really useful regex tester